# EntityFramework and ADO.NET together?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a reason why I couldn't use both EF and ADO.NET in my solution? The latter to handle the more intensive database calls that require faster processing, yet EF for the ORM benefits (code first)???

Comment: Use the "easy way". Until the "easy way" is *shown* not to be fast/good enough. I use LINQ2SQL (wrapped in a DAL) for most work, but also have various Database Views that are accessed via [Typed]DataSets (mainly for use with reporting and complex rollups) when I need to get down'n'dirty with the database. There are also a few SProcs in use for when "they are just significantly faster" (upserts from a bulk import, mostly). That being said, I do not believe in code-first: I'm a *model first* kind of guy ;-) But if EF/code-first is your style, then go with it and then identify/fix hotspots later.

Comment: Although, EF is a wrapper on top of ADO.NET, you can actually use stored procedures and functions from EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a misunderstanding, the EF and ADO.NET are actually working together.
Look at the overview [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Also a post that shows usage of stored procedure starting from EF4: [A big step for Stored Procedures in EF4](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/)

Comment: Thank you...there are a few spots where I need to get down'n'dirty with the db. My complex Linq to Entities is running so slow!

Comment: No problem, i has same issues on EF. As i remember, it is better to call sproc each time you are performing set base operations in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

EF is built on top of ADO.Net, meaning that you can use both at the same time.